# Is (3) a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ $(\sqrt{-17})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, alternative-proof, group-rings

First, I had to prove that  $\mathbb{Z}$ $(\sqrt{-17})$ is not a UFD which was done by showing that in general $\mathbb{Z}$ $(\sqrt{-n})$ for $n \geq 3$ is not a UFD. Subsequently, I was asked if (3) is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ $(\sqrt{-17})$.

Is it enough to say that 3 divides the product $(1+\sqrt{-17})(1-\sqrt{-17})=18$ but does not divide either of the factors thus it is not a prime ideal?

Is there another way of showing it using, perchance, the UFD definition?

Comment: What's your definition of "prime ideal"?

Comment: @MichaelMorrow If a and b are two elements of R such that their product ab is an element of P, then a is in P or b is in P

Comment: Do you see how to relate your definition of prime ideal to your example of $1+\sqrt{-17}$ and $1-\sqrt{-17}$?

Comment: Yes, it definitely is enough.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow do you mean that $1+\sqrt{-17}$ and $1-\sqrt{-17}$ are elements of the ring and their product is an element of the ideal, but they do not belong to the ideal?

Comment: Yep, because belonging to the ideal $(3)$ is the same as being divisible by $3$.